# Chrome extension app is not showing logo image after get installed

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have created google chrome extension and uploaded it into chrome webstore. When i installed it from chrome webstore link it is working fine but when i'm looking it into my chrome installed extensions list through tool>extensions, it is there in list but there is no logo image, it is having a default image not that one i submitted during upload. Is there any idea?

Comment: You'll need to post your manifest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image you submit during upload is for use in the Web Store and other "marketing" purposes. The icons you see when you install it are the ones you have bundled with the extension and declared in the manifest (see **[the docs](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/icons.html)**).